# Do you say "I just knew" or "I knew(know) just now" about something you realised very recently?

Tags: word-choice

> I ***just knew/knew just now*** the store is closed so now I don't know where to go to get my stuff.

Do you say *"just knew"* or *"knew(know) just now"* if you realise something very recently? And will it be any real difference in meaning between *"knew just now"* and *"know just now"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. You would say, "I just found out the store is closed", or "Just now, I discovered the store is closed".  If you were disappointed you might say, "I just knew the store would be closed", but you're expressing an opinion about a previous state of mind, rather than reporting the fact of the store not being open.

Comment: Is this usage wrong then? _I knew just now, the author who wrote a book that taught me basic knowledge of algorithm sat near of me._ [source](https://twitter.com/kaztak_en/status/27754802855284736)

Comment: Yes, that sounds strange to a native speaker. It makes no sense to combine a simple past tense statement, 'I knew', with the present immediacy of 'just now'. In Polish you can make that construction, but there the notion of 'now' encompasses a much broader swathe of time.